# Impact of using relu for gradient descent

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent, derivative, activation-function

What impact does the fact the relu activation function does not contain a derivative ?

[How to implement the ReLU function in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109319/how-to-implement-the-relu-function-in-numpy) implements relu as maximum of (0 , matrix vector elements).

Does this mean for gradient descent we do not take derivative of relu function ?

Update :

From [Neural network backpropagation with RELU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546020/neural-network-backpropagation-with-relu)

this text aids in understanding :

> The ReLU function is defined as: For x > 0 the output is x, i.e. f(x)
>   = max(0,x)
>
> So for the derivative f '(x) it's actually:
>
> if x < 0, output is 0. if x > 0, output is 1.
>
> The derivative f '(0) is not defined. So it's usually set to 0 or you
>   modify the activation function to be f(x) = max(e,x) for a small e.
>
> Generally: A ReLU is a unit that uses the rectifier activation
>   function. That means it works exactly like any other hidden layer but
>   except tanh(x), sigmoid(x) or whatever activation you use, you'll
>   instead use f(x) = max(0,x).
>
> If you have written code for a working multilayer network with sigmoid
>   activation it's literally 1 line of change. Nothing about forward- or
>   back-propagation changes algorithmically. If you haven't got the
>   simpler model working yet, go back and start with that first.
>   Otherwise your question isn't really about ReLUs but about
>   implementing a NN as a whole.

But this still leaves some confusion as the neural network cost function typically takes derivative of activation function, so for relu how does this impact cost function ?

Comment: It means you might lose all the guarantees in regards to GD (wiki calls it *ill-defined*).

Comment: The text in the update does not address the question: (1): this is an sub-gradient. (2): the sub-gradient might be used in SGD; but not in plain GD.

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer is that the input to ReLU is rarely exactly zero, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222534/relus-and-gradient-descent-for-deep-neural-nets) for example, so it doesn't make any significant difference.

Specifically, for ReLU to get a zero input, the dot product of one entire row of the input to a layer with one entire column of the layer's weight matrix would have to be exactly zero. Even if you have an all-zero input sample, there should still be a bias term in the last position, so I don't really see this ever happening.

However, if you want to test for yourself, try implementing the derivative at zero as `0`, `0.5`, and `1` and see if anything changes.

The PyTorch docs give a [simple neural network with numpy example](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html#warm-up-numpy) with one hidden layer and relu activation. I have reproduced it below with a fixed random seed and three options for setting the behavior of the ReLU gradient at 0. I have also added a bias term.

```
N, D_in, H, D_out = 4, 2, 30, 1

# Create random input and output data
x = x = np.random.randn(N, D_in)
x = np.c_(x, no.ones(x.shape[0]))
y = x = np.random.randn(N, D_in)

np.random.seed(1)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = np.random.randn(D_in+1, H)
w2 = np.random.randn(H, D_out)

learning_rate = 0.002
loss_col = []
for t in range(200):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.dot(w1)
    h_relu = np.maximum(h, 0)  # using ReLU as activate function
    y_pred = h_relu.dot(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = np.square(y_pred - y).sum() # loss function
    loss_col.append(loss)
    print(t, loss, y_pred)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y) # the last layer's error
    grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.dot(w2.T) # the second laye's error 
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.copy()        
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0  # grad at zero = 1
    # grad[h <= 0] = 0 # grad at zero = 0
    # grad_h[h < 0] = 0; grad_h[h == 0] = 0.5 # grad at zero = 0.5
    grad_w1 = x.T.dot(grad_h)

    # Update weights
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```